# Word for the group of people who supporting a corrupt leader

Tags: word-request

What can I name the group of people those who are following a bad/corrupt leader, supporting his all kind of activities (even knowing their leader is corrupted) and never give up their leader with others in any arguments, as always saying that his leader is genuine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word **henchmen** comes to mind, **cadre** might also be possible, or the obvious phrase **corrupt followers**.

> Mugabe and his **henchmen**
>   Mugabe and his **cadre**
>   Mugabe and his **corrupt followers**

Answer (score 5):

I like Peter's suggestion of *henchmen*. Another alternative is ***cronies***.

From NOAD:

> **crony** *noun* (pl. **cronies**) `informal, often derogatory`
>   a close friend or companion: *he went gambling with his cronies*.

The dictionary mentions this is often used as a derogatory term, so it conveys the negative sentiment you are looking for.

Incidentally, NOAD adds an even stronger label under *henchmen*: `chiefly derogatory`.

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/crony) defines *crony* as:

> **crony** *noun* a friend or supporter, especially of someone powerful

so the word also conveys the notion of supporting a leader. Macmillan adds a negative usage note, too, mentioning that the word is used for `showing disapproval`.

Answer (score -1):

You might like this term: [Kakistocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakistocracy)

From the link:

> A kakistocracy (English pronunciation: /kækɪsˈtɑkɹəsi/) is a system of government which is run by the worst, least qualified, or most unscrupulous citizens.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakistocracy)[2] The word was coined as early as the 17th century.[3] It was also used by English author Thomas Love Peacock in 1829, but gained significant usage in the 21st century.

Comment: Hi @Scott, I edited to add the Wikipedia link. But kindly edit further in case the source (or something else) does not match. Also, please, please, please provide explanation, as your original answer isn't a good reference. Note that SE is not a forum. Always bear in mind that we are creating a collection of useful (and additional) knowledge for readers, learners and the rest of humanity (exaggeration intended).